# a question about forms in powershell

Tags: forms, powershell

my script uses two forms. i want to close second form after opening first one. how can i do it?

Comment: i get some data from ERP by webservices while user is logging on. getting data takes some time, nearly half a minute. i want to show to user that data is collecting and everything is fine with his pc. when data is collected i show it in form in listview object, before it happened he sees nothing, just a clear background.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PowerShell has a built-in mechanism to report progress - a cmdlet called Write-Progress.  Give it a try:

```
for ($i = 0; $i -le 100; $i +=5)
{
    Write-Progress -Activity "Collecting ERP data" -Status "Downloading..." `
                   -PercentComplete $i
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 1
}
```

Comment: thank you. that's cool cmdlet. how do i know when i stopped collecting data?

Comment: I don't know enough about your particular scenario but presumably when the web service call returns you're done collecting data, right? At that point, you can make the Write-Progress display disappear by calling `Write-Progress -Activity "Collecting ERP data" -Status "Downloading..." -Completed`.

Comment: thank you. it helped. i should read mans more thoroughly.